# pymysql stopped working : NameError: name 'byte2int' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, pymysql

I am using pymysql in Python to connect to database. It was working fine but now I am getting following `error` :

Traceback (most recent call last) :

```
  File "/Users/njethani/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/njethani/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 327, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/njethani/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 598, in connect
    self._request_authentication()
  File "/Users/njethani/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 865, in _request_authentication
    data = _auth.scramble_old_password(self.password, self.salt) + b'\0'
  File "/Users/njethani/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/_auth.py", line 72, in scramble_old_password
    hash_pass = _hash_password_323(password)
  File "/Users/njethani/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/_auth.py", line 97, in _hash_password_323
    for c in [byte2int(x) for x in password if x not in (' ', '\t', 32, 9)]:
  File "/Users/njethani/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/_auth.py", line 97, in <listcomp>
    for c in [byte2int(x) for x in password if x not in (' ', '\t', 32, 9)]:
NameError: name 'byte2int' is not defined
```

I am using following lines to connect to my database (connection string) :

```
conn = pymysql.Connect(host='hostname', port=3306, user='username', passwd='password', db='mysql')
```

Answer (score 5):

Since the pymysql maintainer [refuses to release the fix](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/pull/713), the solution is simply to install an older version of the package:

```
pip3 install --user 'pymysql<0.9'
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and looked like _auth.py was unable to find the reference of byte2int. I added the below line to modify _auth.py to make it work.

from util import byte2int,int2byte

Please be aware the util.py is that of pymysql as there will be util.py files in other packages as well.

Comment: @JulianCamilleri unfortunately I don't think these changes have been released to pypi yet.